# Changing of integration and operator

Tags: real-analysis, hilbert-spaces

I have a question which maybe looks very simple: Let $T$ be an orthogonal projection on a Hilbert space $H$. If $g(x,u)\in H$, for all $u\in \mathbb R$, and the inner product is defined by 
$$\langle f(.), g(.,u)\rangle_{H}=\int_{\mathbb R}f(x)g(x,u)dx $$
which is a function of $u$ (say $h(u)$), for all $f\in H$.

Now my question is that if we apply the projection to the resulting function $h(u)$, can we move the projection inside the integral, i.e.:

$$T (h(u))= T\big( \int_{\mathbb R}f(x)g(x,u)dx \big)= \int_{\mathbb R}f(x)T(g(x,u))dx$$

(If this is not always true what are the cases where we can do this?)

Comment: Is $T$ an operator on functions or values?

Comment: @copper.hat: $T$ is an orthogonal projection on functions from $H$. I think I know what you are thinking of: is the function $h$ belongs to $H$ or not!! So lets assume thats true.

Comment: Well, no. In the above equation, $T$ operates on elements of $H$. But inside the integral, it is operating on the range of $g$.

Comment: The idea is that any function $f\in H$ can be writen as $f(u)=\langle f(x),g(x,u)\rangle$, so I want to know if $T(f)=\langle f(x),T(g(x,u))\rangle$. (Maybe this is more clear!)

Comment: I see; the notation was confusing me. I would use the notation $T(\int f(x)g(x,\cdot)dx = \int f(x) T(g(x,\cdot)) dx$. This makes it clear that you are performing vector (as in $\in H$) valued integrations

Comment: Let $g_u\in H$ be the function defined by $g_u(x)=g(x,u)$.  Where you wrote "$T(g(x,u))$", do you actually mean "$(T(g_u))(x)$?  Also, where you wrote "$T(h(u))$", a pedant like me would write $(Th)(u)$, indicating that $T$ sends $h$ to the function $Th$, which is then evaluated at $u$.  This may be what copper.hat was confused about, or maybe it's just me.

Comment: I think the issue here is how you define and assure the existence of the vector valued integral. Assuming this is not an issue, most vector integration schemes satisfy $\phi(\int f d\mu) = \int \phi(f) d\mu$, $\forall \phi \in H^*$. So, in your case, the interchange would be justified if $T$ is continuous.

Comment: Let me see if I understand the question.  For each $f\in H$, let $h_f(u)=\langle f(\cdot),g(\cdot,u)\rangle$, and assume that $h_f$ is in $H$.  Given an orthogonal projection $T$ on $H$, is it true that $(Th_f)(u) = \langle f(\cdot),Tg(\cdot,u)\rangle$?  This would be equivalent to $Th_f = h_{T^*f}=h_{Tf}$ (with the last equality because $T^*=T$).

Comment: My model was if $h = \sum f_i g_i$, where $f_i$ are scalars, and $g_i \in H$, then $T(h) = \sum f_i T(g_i)$. So, I view '$x$' as an index as such. (Also, I don't think it is pedantic, I think much confusion would disappear with better choices.)

Comment: @Jonas Meyer: Yes, this is what I want! So is it true?

Comment: @Kim: Well, it would be true in the case of your second comment, in which $h_f=f$ for all $f\in H$, and therefore $Th_f=Tf=h_{Tf}$.  (And this only uses the fact that $T=T^*$.) I don't see why it would be true in a more general setting, but haven't thought about it enough.

Comment: @Jonas Meyer: I just need it for the case where $h_{f}=f, f\in H$. But How to give an explicit proof for this?

Answer (score 1):

This answer will first formulate a more precise statement of the special case that came out in the comments, and then show why it is true.

Suppose that $H$ is a (real) Hilbert space of real-valued functions on $\mathbb R$ with $L^2$ inner product.  Suppose that $g:\mathbb R\times \mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ is a function such that for all $u\in \mathbb R$, $g(\cdot, u)$ is in $H$, and for all $f\in H$, $f(u)=\langle f,g(\cdot,u)\rangle$.

Claim: If $T$ is a symmetric linear operator on $H$, then for all $f\in H$ and $u\in \mathbb R$, $(Tf)(u)=\langle f,Tg(\cdot,u)\rangle$.

Proof: $(Tf)(u)=\langle Tf,g(\cdot,u)\rangle=\langle f,T^*g(\cdot,u)\rangle=\langle f,Tg(\cdot,u)\rangle,$ because $T=T^*$.